# How to fix a div tag and make all subsequent content appear outside the div

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have the following HTML/CSS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html,body {
          height: 100%;
        }
        body {
          margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width: 20%; height: 100%; background-color: red">Text Inside the div</div>
    Text Outside the div
</body>
</html>
```

I want it so that all the subsequent text after the `<div style="width: 20%; height: 100%; background-color: red">Text Inside the div</div>` appears directly to the right of that div tag, rather than starting at the left of the browser again. Is there a way to do this, other than having another div tag after the first one and doing something like shifting it to the right/floating?

Comment: Would you mind [accepting my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if i have solved your question please ?

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are after. You can use `display: inline-flex` to achieve that.

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>Text Inside the div</div>Text Outside the div
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want your text after the div to flow right after the div to the right of it?
If so, you can use flexbox on the body:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html,body {
          height: 100%;
        }
        body {
          margin: 0;
display:flex;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width: 20%; height: 100%; background-color: red">Text Inside the div</div>
    Text Outside the div
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to control the position / behaviour of two elements relative to each other I'd suggest looking at how you can modify their parent element. In this case, setting the parent to display:flex will help.

Note that you'll need to set the width of the parent to take up the whole width of the browser viewport for your 20% width div to know how to size itself.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html,body {
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
          display: flex;
        }
        body, p {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width: 20%; height: 100%; background-color: red">Text Inside the div</div>
        Text Outside the div
</body>
</html>
```